# React Native Redux Saga takeLatest method not getting called

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native, redux-saga

I am a newbie in react native. I am implementing redux saga in my app. but the saga request for fetch method is not called on 'Random photos list' text click.
Here is my code:

> App.js

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// Imports: Screens
import Counter from './Counter';
// Imports: Redux Store
import { store } from '../Stores/store';
// React Native App
export default function App() {
  return (
    // Redux: Global Store
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Counter />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

> Counter.js

```
render() {
    debugger;
    return (

      <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.fetchData}>
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Random Photos List</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
          <FlatList
          data={this.props.photos}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.showAlert() }>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer1}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle1}>{item.id}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer2}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle2}>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  debugger;
  console.log('State:');
  console.log(state);
  // Redux Store --> Component
  return {
    photos: state.photos.photos
  };
};
// Map Dispatch To Props (Dispatch Actions To Reducers. Reducers Then Modify The Data And Assign It To Your Props)
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    fetchData: () => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_PHOTO_REQUESTED' })
  }
}
// Exports
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

> Reducer/index.js

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// Imports: Reducers
import counterReducer from './counterReducer';
// Redux: Root Reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  photos: counterReducer,
});
// Exports
export default rootReducer;
```

> CounterReducer.js

```
const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS':
    return {
                ...state,
                photos: action.payload
          }
    default:
      return state;
}
};
// Exports
export default counterReducer;
```

> store.js

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
// Imports: Redux Root Reducer
import rootReducer from '../Reducers/index';
// Imports: Redux Root Saga
import { rootSaga } from '../Sagas/index';
// Middleware: Redux Saga
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
// Redux: Store
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    sagaMiddleware,
    createLogger(),
  ),
);
// Middleware: Redux Saga
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
// Exports
export {
  store,
}
```

> Sagas/index.js

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { all, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects';
// Imports: Redux Sagas
import {fetchPhotos} from './counterSaga';
// Redux Saga: Root Saga
export  function* rootSaga() {
    yield fork(fetchPhotos);
}
```

and

> counterSaga.js

```
import { delay, takeEvery, takeLatest, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* fetchPhotosAsync() {
  try {
    const payload = yield call(getData);
    debugger;
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_PHOTO_SUCCESS', payload });
  } catch (e) {
    debugger;
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_PHOTO_ERROR', payload: e });
  }
}

function getData() {
  debugger;
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(response =>
    response.json()
  );
}

// Watcher: Increase Counter Async
export function* fetchPhotos() {
  // Take Last Action Only
  debugger;
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_PHOTO_REQUESTED', fetchPhotosAsync);
};
```

I have been debugging for 2 days now. still not able to find the cause. Please Help.
Any Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you use `call` instead of `fork`: `yield call(fetchPhotos);` ?

Comment: @Clarity nope if i replace export  function* rootSaga() {
    yield fork(fetchPhotos);
} with export  function* rootSaga() {
    yield call(fetchPhotos);
}            it throws exception can't find variable :call

Comment: Also it in the question your `CounterSaga` file name is uppercased but you import from lowecase file.

Comment: my bad, it's a typo in question.

Comment: when you replace `fork` with `call`, you need to import call from `redux-saga/effects`.

Comment: thanks a lot, the import 'call'  was missing in "counterSaga.js"